# Here-lite: RasterLayer with file tile source

Tags: here-api

In the Android Here-lite SDK custom layers are added with the RasterLayer object. In the documented example, custom tiles are taken from an url:

```
RasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer(offlineRasterLayerName,
            "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            19, 1000);
```

Is it possible to use a file source residing on the local file system instead?

```
RasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer(offlineRasterLayerName,
            "file://path/to/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            19, 1000);
```

Did not work so far.

Comment: Maybe try "file:///path/to/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"? If you need to access local files use "file:///" as protocol ...

Comment: with file protocol it seems to work, so I am a little bit confused, as the answer from @HERE Developer Support below states the opposite.

Comment: Probably it's best to treat this as hidden feature until it is officially supported. :)

Comment: Update: This no longer works in the newer versions. Probably, there was never really support or maintenance for this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to use a file source from local system ,as per the documentation it is should be on your own server where you host tiles that you want to show as an overlay on top of selected areas of the world.

> RasterLayer(java.lang.String layerName, **java.lang.String url**, long
> maxZoom, long drawOrder)
>
> The format of the URL should be as follows: https://YourRasterTileService.com/zoom/xTile/yTile.png

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/api_reference/com/here/sdk/mapviewlite/RasterLayer.html#url

Hope this helps.